# android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS error

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to modify some settings on my phone through the app but I keep getting 
this error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

I have added this permission to my manifest but the error still remains.
Here is a snippet from my manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"
    android:maxSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"
    android:maxSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    android:maxSdkVersion="11" />
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="11"
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

Note: It is not good to use `android:maxSdkVersion` in manifest. You can remove it.

Comment: What is the purpose for remove? It's just working fine with maxSdkVersion in my case

Comment: @MD as per docs: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible.

Answer (score 4):

Android doc says,

> **android:maxSdkVersion**
>     The highest API level at which this permission should be granted to your app. Setting this attribute is
>   useful if the permission your app requires is no longer needed
>   beginning at a certain API level.
>
> ```
> <uses-permission
>      android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
>      android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
> ```
>
> This way, beginning with API level 19, the system will no longer grant
>   your app the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

In which SDK version do you run this code?

For Android version 11 & below, permission will be granted as per your code.

If you do not want to limit the permission with respect to particular sdk versions, remove the maxSdkVersion attribute.